# React-admin table displays twice

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-admin

From some reason the code I write here build 2 tables and displaying both.
I tried to re-write it many times and still displaying 2 tables.

[image]

users.js
[image]

results:

[image]

what should I try?

Answer (score 1):

The `<Admin>` component should only have `<Resource>` components as children. Your `<Users>` component should be passed as the `list` prop of a resource:

```
const App = () =>
   <Admin dataProvider={myDataProvider}>
       <Resource list={Users} />
   </Admin>;
```

This is well documented in https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html#mapping-api-endpoints-with-resources

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you loaded the entire `App` component twice. To test that you can try to render some string in the `App` component. It could also be that `Admin` renders `Users` already.

Comment: well I tried but still..
It doesn't render the string twice.

Comment: Without the full code it won't be easy for us to guess. Try standard debugging techniques: remove code until it does not happen anymore, or remove a lot and add lines one by one until you get what you want.